# ERROR opening socket: Success

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0);
    {
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    }
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if(connect(sockfd, &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        error("ERROR connecting");
    }
    printf("Please enter the message:");
    bzero(buffer, 256);
    fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
    n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if (n <0)
    {
       error("ERROR reading from socket");
    }
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, I got the error

```
ERROR opening socket: Success
```

then the program does nothing. Also, I got the warning that

```
 warning: passing argument 2 of ‘connect’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 if(connect(sockfd,&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
 ^
In file included from Clientown.c:3:0:
/usr/include/sys/socket.h:138:12: note: expected ‘const struct sockaddr *’ but argument is of type ‘struct sockaddr_in *’
extern int connect (int __fd, __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG __addr, socklen_t __len);
```

How is this happening? I am new to c and I really stuck with this code. Is there something wrong with the connect? Does the warning matter? Can someone help to me fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "does nothing"? Does it successfully terminate? Or crash? Or hang up? As a side note, in case of an error use `exit(1)`, not `exit(0)`. Also, if the number of command-line parameters is <3, you probably want to exit, too.

Comment: when exiting a program due to an error, use `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` NOT `exit(0);` as a 0 return code indicates the program was successful.

Answer (score 2):

You have a semicolon where there should not be a semicolon:

```
if (sockfd < 0);
{
    error("ERROR opening socket");
}
```

As a result, the `error()` function will always be called, even if the if condition fails. You want:

```
if (sockfd < 0)
{
    error("ERROR opening socket");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Penguin Brian [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42618162/1475978) the stated question, but I'd like to point out that since the asker is using POSIX/BSD sockets, they should also use the proper interfaces, namely [`getaddrinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html). It handles both name and port/service translation, and supports IPv4 and IPv6 (allowing the caller to restrict to either one if desired, of course).

The [`man 3 getaddrinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) man page does include two example programs (client and server type), but here's mine, for illustration, with sufficient error checking:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints, *list, *curr;
    const char     *host, *port;
    int             sockfd, result;

    if (argc != 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("       %s host port\n", argv[0]);
        printf("\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    host = argv[1];
    port = argv[2];

    /* "" or "-" host refers to loopback. */
    if (!host[0] || (host[0] == '-' && !host[1])) 
        host = NULL;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;        /* IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    /* TCP */
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG;

    list = NULL;
    result = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &list);
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s.\n", gai_strerror(result));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (curr = list; curr; curr = curr->ai_next) {

        sockfd = socket(curr->ai_family, curr->ai_socktype, curr->ai_protocol);
        if (sockfd == -1)
            continue;

        if (connect(sockfd, curr->ai_addr, curr->ai_addrlen) != -1)
            break;

        close(sockfd);
        sockfd = -1;
    }

    if (sockfd == -1) {
        freeaddrinfo(list);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot connect.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Descriptor %d is now connected. Disconnecting.\n", sockfd);
    fflush(stdout);

    if (close(sockfd)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing socket: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Done.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that the above code does not record or report the error messages from the `connect()` call, because the `getaddrinfo()` interface provides multiple alternatives, and I'm not sure *which* of the errors produced in a typical case is the proper one to report. (Remember that even in a successful connection case, one or more of the `connect()` calls in the loop may have failed, without any actual "error" having occurred.) The `getaddrinfo()` call itself will fail if the host (node) or port (service) part is invalid.

In my own applications, I tend to use an error cookie -- one bit per error -- to record all the errors from the `connect()` calls for one result list from a `getaddrinfo()` call. The errors I test for are `EADDRINUSE` (local port already in use), `ECONNREFUSED` (connection refused), `ENETUNREACH` (network unreachable), `EACCES` (permission denied), `EADDRNOTAVAIL` (all ephemeral ports already in use), `EAFNOSUPPORT` (address family (IPv4/IPv6) not supported), and a catch-all for all other errors.

If none of the `connect()` calls succeed, I check the cookie for errors that did occur -- as an unordered set; i.e., ignoring the *order* in which they occurred --, and report the first match to the above list. It's not foolproof by any measure, more like trying-to-be-helpful heuristic, and I suspect that a generic error message ("Cannot connect" or similar -- this is what browsers do, after all) is generally just as useful to most users.

Comment: Strongly agreed. We should be writing all new code to support both IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

On the second question: You pass a pointer to a specific **Internet** socket address structure, but `connect` expects a generic socket address structure, so simply cast one type of pointer to the other:

```
connect(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)
```

This warning is actually almost irrelevant, since all pointer types on modern architectures have the same size.